# insert string with special characters into KDB+

Tags: kdb

What type should I use to create a table in KDB+ and insert a string with special charcters: spaces, #, -, etc. - it looks like KDB+ treat all these and similar characters specially, because when I create a table like this:

```
t: ([] str: ())
```

And insert the string `"abc # efgf - ABC.FS #.... TEST            TEST"` - long string with different characters, including spaces, - and # like this:

```
`t insert "abc # efgf - ABC.FS #.... TEST            TEST"
```

KDB returns type exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here doesn't come from the special characters, it comes from the fact that a string is a list of characters. You need to use `enlist` to insert the string as a single element into the table.

In fact, this case is a bit atypical because you only have one column in the table, so you actually need to use `enlist` twice, as kdb expects a list of column data as the second argument in `insert`. So for this table use

```
`t insert enlist enlist "blah blah # # #"
```

If you had a table with more than one column, then you only need one enlist for the string, e.g.

```
t:([]id:(); str:())
`t insert (1; enlist "blah blah # # #")
```

Comment: Thanks, I also discovered why I had problems with string insertion. Instead of spaces I had some special spaces. My java code in the debug mode showed them as '\u' characters. After I removed them, everything looks fine. But still interested how KX may process this characters so I won't need to clean up.

Comment: Do you mean unicode characters? If so, there is some information on unicode in KDB on the [KX wiki](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Cookbook/Unicode).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you get `'type` error though as mine got `'length` error...

Anyway, `insert` expect right hand side to be a list containing items that match the number of columns. i.e.

```
q)t:([]a:();b:())
q)`t insert (1;2)    / single record matching 2 columns
,0
```

To `insert` multiple records, right hand side will be a nested list, each item is a list.

```
q)`t insert (2 3;4 5)
1 2
```

So in your case, to insert a single record of string, you need a singleton list that contains an enlisted string:

```
q)t: ([] str: ())
q)`t insert enlist enlist "abc # efgf - ABC.FS #.... TEST TEST"
,0
q)t
str
-------------------------------------
"abc # efgf - ABC.FS #.... TEST TEST"
```